# WhiteSpace in Unix File

Tags: unix

would like to know what are the white space characters that can we expect from a Unix File and how are they are represented

Below are the ones that i can think Off

\n = new line
\t = tab

Help much appreciated ?

Answer (score 0):

Since question is completely vague, the only answer I could think of is `man isspace`:

```
isspace()
   checks for white-space characters.  In the "C" and "POSIX" locales, these
   are: space, form-feed ('\f'), newline  ('\n'),  carriage  return  ('\r'),
   horizontal tab ('\t'), and vertical tab ('\v').
```